# alternative to sql server 2005

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I got used to the xml support and recursive common table expressions of sql server 2005. I am just wondering whether any free dbs like mysql support these requirements nowadays? Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Don't forget the express editions are free, although you don't say how you intend to use this (web host/embedded/etc.)

Comment: express only goes to 4GB. Eventually, it should be web hosted but I am looking for a free version for local development at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has support for XML, CTE's, windowing functions, etc. etc. etc. And it's not limited to a lousy 4GB. It also runs on Linux, Windows, etc.

Edit: MySQL doesn't support XML nor CTE's, nor windowing functions.

Comment: does it support recursive ctes though?

Edit: seems to: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme great

Comment: Yes, version 8.4 does. Also, I find working with XML is much smoother in Postgres/Oracle (same syntax) than in SQL Server.